# Contour Extraction from Scanned Raster Image in Qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-processing

I have a scanned raster image containing contours and rivers. I am trying to use qgis to extract these contour and river polylines for analysis. As a start I was thinking of the following process based on the properties of the file:
 - making image bitonal
 - sharpening of narrowing scanned lines
 - connecting broken lines
 - removing unwanted scanned text
 - converting remaining lines to contour lines

can someone assist me on how the above can be accomplished in Qgis?